# Loading flash on selenium webdriver

Tags: python, linux, flash, selenium, firefox

On my ubuntu server I can't get firefox to load any flash element though the plugin is listed as being installed. I even built the plugin manually.

Plugin listed:http://puu.sh/rz74I/2d0bfbaa07.png
Page tested on: http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

The page will not load the flash element at all using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get('http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/')
ff.save_screenshot('test.png')
ff.close()
```

produces a weird result, this is using Xvfb as well.